# Joining two tables with LINQ while also returning null records from the second table

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I have tables `Message` and `Image` that I'm joining. The tables look like this:

```
Message(MessageID, TimeStamp, Text, RoomID, ImageID, UserID)
Image(ImageID, Path, Type, UserID)
```

Not all messages will have an `ImageID`. Here's my current join:

```
List<Message> messages = Message.GetAll();
List<Image> images = Image.GetAll();

var resultTable = from m in messages 
    join i in images 
    on m.ImageID equals i.ImageID
    select new
    {
        MessageID = m.MessageID,
        TimeStamp = m.TimeStamp,
        Text = m.Text,
        RoomID = m.RoomID,
        ImageID = m.ImageID,
        UserID = m.UserID,
        Path = i.Path // Nullable
    };
```

I then bind `resultTable` to a `ListView` that needs the `Path` column from the `Image` table. My current join only returns messages with images. How would I select all messages, but if the message has an `ImageID != null`, then assign it a value for `Path`? I assume I should change this line: `on m.ImageID equals i.ImageID` at minimum.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're currently doing an inner join, but you can use [DefaultIfEmpty() to create a left outer join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx). This will also return the null records.

```
var resultTable = from m in messages 
    join i in images on m.ImageID equals i.ImageID into imgJoin
    from img in imgJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new
    {
        MessageID = m.MessageID,
        TimeStamp = m.TimeStamp,
        Text = m.Text,
        RoomID = m.RoomID,
        ImageID = m.ImageID,
        UserID = m.UserID,
        Path = img != null ? img.Path : ""
    };
```

Comment: One minor adjustment to `from x in imgJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()` and `Path = x != null ? x.Path : ""` and it worked! Many thanks. Change your answer and I'll accept.

Comment: I marked as answer, but I was wondering if someone could explain why 'img' in the example would be null? To me, it seems odd that DefaultIfEmpty does not return an empty default object. Thanks!